# QTP identifies the webtable during reording. However when the similar properties are defined in Object repository,table is not identified

Tags: qtp

Hi I am using below code to test my webpage.

```
ExecuteFile "H:\Asma\wp_CommonFunctions.vbs"

Set Brw_Composer = CreateObjectDescription("name:=Composer - Test Accounts")
Set Page_Composer = CreateObjectDescription("title:=Composer.*,url:=http://sharepoint.btfin.com.*")
Set tbl_Composer_HostBrand = CreateObjectDescription("html tag:=TABLE,Value:=36,text:=Host Brand.*,Enable Smart Identification:=True,rows:=16")
Set tbl_Composer_Environments = CreateObjectDescription("html tag:=TABLE,Value:=32")

BT_SVP_Path= "http://sharepoint.btfin.com/it/simt/home/environments%20tech/Composer/Test%
SystemUtil.Run BT_SVP_Path

' Get the value of CAN  under 
cellValue=Browser("Composer - Test Accounts").Page("Composer - Test Accounts").WebTable("Host Brand").GetCellData(12,4)

'Open SVP ACC2 Ingress link
'Set obj = Browser(Brw_Composer).Page(Page_Composer).Webtable(tbl_Composer_Environments)
If  (Browser(Brw_Composer).Page(Page_Composer).Webtable(tbl_Composer_Environments)).Exist Then
    msgbox" success"
else 
    msgbox "failure"
End If
'****************************************************************** 
Function CreateObjectDescription(StrProperties)
    Dim objDescription 
    Dim ObjArr 
    Dim PropCount
    Dim ObjProperty
    Set objDescription=Description.Create 
    ObjArr=split(StrProperties,",") 
    For PropCount=0 to ubound(ObjArr) 
        ObjProperty=split(ObjArr(PropCount),":=")
        objDescription(ObjProperty(0)).value=ObjProperty(1) 
    Next 
    Set CreateObjectDescription=objDescription
End Function
```

Webtables are not identified during runtime if their properties are specified during runtime.If i add their properties in object repository the code works fine. 
Please help. I am using IE 6 for testing my webapp.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between Object Repository (OR) descriptions and Descriptive Programming (DP) is that OR is by default non-regex and DP is regex.

This may be what is causing the difference in behaviour, if this is the case just add

```
objDescription(ObjProperty(0)).RegularExpression = False
```

Another difference can be to do with hidden properties the OR sometimes uses. In order to see if this is the cause go to `Tools -> Options -> Web -> Advanced` and un-check *Run using source index* (and if you're using QTP11 also *Learn and run using automatic XPath identifiers*). Now see if the identification from the OR still works.

If the behaviour is still different between OR and DP there's probably a difference in your identifications properties.

Comment: Thanks for help.I am able to identify Browser and Page through this however webtables are not getting identified. Is there any thing else i can do?

Comment: @asmarazavi have you tried my suggestions? What were the results?